# "CASE WHEN" in WHERE clause with indexed columns

Tags: mysql, function, key, case, where-clause

I have a function with CASE WHEN condition in WHERE clause. Simply (very simply) it looks like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable t
WHERE (
   CASE aPARAM WHEN 'a' THEN t.a = aID
               WHEN 'b' THEN t.b = aID
               WHEN 'c' THEN t.c = aID
               ELSE TRUE END
)
```

**aPARAM** and **aID** - function params

**a**, **b** and **c** - indexed columns of the table "mytable"

But in this case MySQL doesn't use indexes at all.

Yes, this query contains condition to select another condition, but it's not depends of result value and can be calculated (defined) before query execute.

What can use suggest to this function to use indexes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Case is an expression for which MySQL can't use indexes. Try converting the case to a bunch of `or` conditions like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable t
WHERE (t.a = aID and aPARAM = 'a')
or (t.b = aID and aPARAM = 'b')
or (t.c = aID and aPARAM = 'c')
or (aPARAM not in ('a','b','c'))
```